# How to use class_weight in custom knowledge distillation model train_step

Tags: python, keras, training-data, imbalanced-data

I want to predict imbalanced data using knowledge distillation keras model.
The y label value count is like this,

```
y_train.value_counts()
0    9024
1     842
Name: Y_LABEL, dtype: int64`
```

To predict imbalanced data, I tried to use class_weight, but I don't know how to apply class_weight in custom model.
How can I apply class_weight in knowledge distillation custom model?

I build Knowledge Distillation Custom Model using keras platform like this,
first, as you can see, y label is imbalanced, so I want to use class_weight

```
class Distiller(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, student, teacher):
        super(Distiller, self).__init__()
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.student = student

    def compile(
        self,
        optimizer,
        metrics,
        student_loss_fn,
        distillation_loss_fn,
        alpha=0.1,
        temperature=3,
    ):
        """ Configure the distiller.
        Args:
            optimizer: Keras optimizer for the student weights
            metrics: Keras metrics for evaluation
            student_loss_fn: Loss function of difference between student
                predictions and ground-truth
            distillation_loss_fn: Loss function of difference between soft
                student predictions and soft teacher predictions
            alpha: weight to student_loss_fn and 1-alpha to distillation_loss_fn
            temperature: Temperature for softening probability distributions.
                Larger temperature gives softer distributions.
        """
        super(Distiller, self).compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
        self.student_loss_fn = student_loss_fn
        self.distillation_loss_fn = distillation_loss_fn
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.temperature = temperature

    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack data
        x, y = data


        # Forward pass of teacher
        teacher_predictions = self.teacher(x[:,:52], training=False)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass of student
            student_predictions = self.student(x[:,52:], training=True)

            # Compute losses
            student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)
            distillation_loss = self.distillation_loss_fn(
                tf.nn.softmax(teacher_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                tf.nn.softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
            )
            loss = self.alpha * student_loss + (1 - self.alpha) * distillation_loss

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.student.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Update the metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions, sample_weight = sample_weight)

        # Return a dict of performance
        results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        results.update(
            {"student_loss": student_loss, "distillation_loss": distillation_loss}
        )
        return results

    def test_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data
        x, y = data

        # Compute predictions
        y_prediction = self.student(x, training=False) # validation_data
        # y_prediction = self.student(x[:,52:], training=False) # validation_split

        # Calculate the loss
        student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, y_prediction)

        # Update the metrics.
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_prediction)

        # Return a dict of performance
        results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        results.update({"student_loss": student_loss})
        return results
```

and here's the class weight
`

```
class_weight
{0: 0.5466568414520633, 1: 5.858270989193683}
```

I compile and fit model like this

```
 distiller.compile(
        student_loss_fn= tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits = True),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()], # , f1
        distillation_loss_fn=keras.losses.KLDivergence(),
        alpha=0.1,
        temperature=10)
```

```
distillarHistory = distiller.fit(
                             df_out, 
                             y_train, 
                             epochs=50,
                             batch_size = 256,
                             validation_data = (X_test_s, y_test),
                             verbose = 0,
                             class_weight = class_weight,
                             )
```

but error occured like this,
how can I apply class_weight in train_step??

```
TypeError: in user code:

File "/home/studio-lab-user/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/home/studio-lab-user/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/home/studio-lab-user/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/tmp/ipykernel_22361/144175027.py", line 61, in train_step
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions, class_weight = class_weight)

TypeError: update_state() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_weight'
```

I tried to use sample_weight by modify custom model like this,

```
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack data
        x, y, sample_weight = data

        # Forward pass of teacher
        teacher_predictions = self.teacher(x[:,:52], training=False)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass of student
            student_predictions = self.student(x[:,52:], training=True)

            # Compute losses
            student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)
            distillation_loss = self.distillation_loss_fn(
                tf.nn.softmax(teacher_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                tf.nn.softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
            )
            loss = self.alpha * student_loss + (1 - self.alpha) * distillation_loss

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.student.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Update the metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions, sample_weight = sample_weight)
        # self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions, sample_weight = sample_weight)

        # Return a dict of performance
        results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        results.update(
            {"student_loss": student_loss, "distillation_loss": distillation_loss}
        )
        return results
```

```
distillarHistory = distiller.fit(
                                 df_out, 
                                 y_train, 
                                 epochs=50,
                                 batch_size = 256,
                                 validation_data = (X_test_s, y_test),
                                 verbose = 0,
                                 sample_weight = sample_weight,
                                 )
```

but the output is exactly the same like not using sample_weight
by using stratified 5 kfold,

- not using sample_weight

```
Alpha - 0.10 / Temperature 10 
62/62 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.561608878542233
62/62 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5664106062792742
62/62 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5908350815131695
62/62 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5793267313367816
62/62 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5918020295603292

--------------------------------------------------------
Alpha=0.1, Temperature=10, F-Score=0.578
--------------------------------------------------------
```

- using sample_weight

```
Alpha - 0.10 / Temperature 10 
62/62 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.561608878542233
62/62 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5664106062792742
62/62 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5908350815131695
62/62 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5793267313367816
62/62 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step
KFold F1 scores :  0.5918020295603292

--------------------------------------------------------
Alpha=0.1, Temperature=10, F-Score=0.578
--------------------------------------------------------
```

`
I wonder is it same to sampling positive data about 10 times much than negative data

Answer (score 0):

Just like in `self.compiled_metrics.update_state`, where you add the argument `sample_weight = sample_weight`, you have to also add the same argument in `self.student_loss_fn` and in `self.distillation_loss_fn`. Hope I helped.